# Delete function error Angular 6 return undefined

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am trying to write a delete function to delete a movie from my object.

This is my code but when I click on a delete button I get DELETE: Error.

What do you think is the error in my code?

You can check out my code here ...

movie-model.ts

```
export class Movie {
  Id: number;
  Title: string;
  Year: number;
  Runtime: string;
  Genre: string;
  Director: string;
}
```

data.service.ts

```
import { Movie } from './model/movie.model';

import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  baseUrl: string = 'http://localhost:4200/';

  getMovies() {
    return fetch('https://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt3896198&apikey=9fa6058b').then(function (resp) {
      return resp.json()
    });
  }

  createMovie(movie:Movie) {
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl, movie);

  }

  deleteMovie(movie:Movie){
    return this.http.delete(this.baseUrl + movie.Id);
  }


}
```

movie-list.component.ts

```
import { DataService } from './../data.service';
import { Movie } from './../model/movie.model';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-movie-list',
  templateUrl: './movie-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./movie-list.component.css']
})
export class MovieListComponent implements OnInit {

  movies = [
    {Id:1, Title: 'Avatar', Year: '2009'},
    {Id:2, Title: 'Harry Potter', Year: '2001'},
    {Id:3, Title: 'Spiderman 3', Year: '2007'}
  ];

  constructor(private dataService:DataService){}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getMovie().then(dt => {
      this.movies.push(dt);

    })
  }

  getMovie() {
    return fetch('https://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt3896198&apikey=9fa6058b').then(function (resp) {
      return resp.json()
    });
  }

  deleteMovie(movie: Movie): void {
    this.dataService.deleteMovie(movie.Id)
      .subscribe( data => {
        this.movies = this.movies.filter(u => u !== movie);
      })
  };
}
```

This is the error I get ...

[image]

What can I do for the delete button to work and give me an alert and then delete itself from the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to acces an endpoint where actually your angular app is running: `baseUrl: string = 'http://localhost:4200/';` This is the default port of your angular application on your local computer, and you try to call an delete endpoint of an external rest api I guess.

But the rest service does not run on your localhost on port 4200, thats why you get a 404 not found. I think you have to call delete on this endpoint `https://www.omdbapi.com`.

EDIT:

If you want delete a movie from your list, you have to delete the entry in your array. The easiest way would be if you change the `id` attribute to `imdbID` because the response type from omdbapi doesn't have an id attribute which means your id will always be undefined. Then when you want to delete an entry you could do it like this:

```
 deleteMovie(imdbID: string): void {
    this.movies = this.movies.filter(m => m.imdbID !== imdbID)
  };
```

It's almost the same code that you have but without the delete call on the rest api. Because you don't want to delete the entry from the database but just on your angular app.

Comment: I am getting this ... Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.omdbapi.com/undefined' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Method DELETE is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response.

Comment: We don't know the rest api which you try to access. Do you have more information or a documentation about which endpoints are exposed by the api? Otherwise it is impossible to help you with that. The Access not allowed is because the rest api does not send any CORS header as response to the options request send by your browser, but this is a thing about how the rest api is designed it has nothing to do with your angular app.

Comment: My rest api is this i guess 'https://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt3896198&apikey=9fa6058b' and I am getting an object which I want to be able to delete or add a new one to it...

Comment: the omdbapi is an rest api to access information about movie data. I don't think that they allow you to delete entries from their database and why would you?. What exactly do you try to achieve? When you want to build an rest api which exposes CRUD Operations then you have to build your own backend with your own database.

Comment: What I am trying to do is after fetching the movie data on my website to be able to have a delete button and delete one of the movies from my website. I dont want to delete it from their api. Just delete the movie so it doesnt show on my website anymore. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Ok Great this is working perfectly thank you so much !!

Comment: Another thing ... What can be working for adding a movie and editing a movie using my code? @J. S.

Answer (score 1):

In the service file you have created method deleteMovie which accept a Movieobject

```
deleteMovie(movie:Movie){
    return this.http.delete(this.baseUrl + movie.Id);
  }
```

But in your Component movie-list.component.ts you are passing id in the delete method

```
import { DataService } from './../data.service';
import { Movie } from './../model/movie.model';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-movie-list',
  templateUrl: './movie-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./movie-list.component.css']
})
export class MovieListComponent implements OnInit {

  movies = [
    {Id:1, Title: 'Avatar', Year: '2009'},
    {Id:2, Title: 'Harry Potter', Year: '2001'},
    {Id:3, Title: 'Spiderman 3', Year: '2007'}
  ];

  constructor(private dataService:DataService){}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getMovie().then(dt => {
      this.movies.push(dt);

    })
  }

  getMovie() {
    return fetch('https://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt3896198&apikey=9fa6058b').then(function (resp) {
      return resp.json()
    });
  }

  deleteMovie(movie: Movie): void { 
    // this.dataService.deleteMovie(movie.Id)    <- Your code error
    // Pass movie object 
       this.dataService.deleteMovie(movie)
      .subscribe( data => {
        this.movies = this.movies.filter(u => u !== movie);
      })
  };
}
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error and also that (u !== movie)will always return true since it has no overlap???